# Last element of a list in a loop

Tags: c++, loops, iterator

I have a `list<Thing*> clothes`. I want to print out `things` to a desired format:

```
+- shirt
+- pants
\\ shoes
```

So basically the output is the same for all but the last iteration. So far I've attempted this:

```
string CCloset::OutputContent() const {
    string output;
    for(auto i : this->clothes) {
        if( next(i) == this->clothes.end() ) {
            output.append("\\");
        } else {
            output.append("+-");
        }

        output.append( i->Output() );
    }
    return output;
}
```

The theory is that if next iteration causes iterator `i` to be at `list.end()` it means we're at the last element so we slightly modify the output. The compiler says `Can't compare structures`.

`next()` returns iterator pointing to the next element. In the case of last element, it would point to past-the-end of list. `list.end()` returns iterator pointing to past-the-end of list.

What am I missing?

Comment: `i` is not an iterator, but just `Thing*`.

Comment: Seems like `std::vector<T>` would be more suitable. It would also likely be faster.

Comment: @Torbjörn thank you, so I would have to use the classic `for(begin, end, incr)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commenters already noted, `i` is not an iterator, but the value of the element.

If you modify the loop to use a reference instead of a value, you can compare the address of the current element with the address of the last element like this:

```
for( const auto& i : this->clothes ) {
    if( &i == &this->clothes.back() ) {
        output.append("\\");
    } else {
        output.append("+-");
    }

    output.append( i->Output() );
}
```

[Live demo on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fafca39aa3ba4e25).

Answer (score 1):

`i` is not an iterator. [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) can only be called with a ForwardIterator or an InputIterator, not with an element of a container.

This is one of the only use-cases for iterator based loops:

```
for(auto it = clothes.begin(); it != clothes.end(); ++it) {
    if( it + 1 == clothes.end() ) {
        output.append("\\");
    } else {
        output.append("+-");
    }

    output.append( (*it)->Output() );
}
```

Comment: Isn't the first condition in the if redundant? The "it != clothes.end()" is already covered by the condition in the for loop.